# RegEx to select all operators (+, -, *, /, =, …) that are not padded with spaces

Tags: regex

I have some Python code without spaces around the operators (well, some have but not all, and some have it only on one side). I need a RegEx for Gedit to find all occurrences of a specific operator (`=`, for example) to be able to replace these with space padded operators of the same type (`=`, in this case). So, this code:

```py
a="a"
b= "b"
b +="b"
c = "c"
```

becomes this:

```py
a = "a"
b = "b"
b += "b"
c = "c"
```

I know how to select every `=` that is not followed by a space:

```py
\,(?=[^\s])
```

But how would I also select those that don't have space before them ? And how do I combine these two RegExes into one ?

Comment: The might be a fancier approach, but a simple one is to replace every = with '<sp>=<sp>' and then in a second pass replace '<sp>+=<sp>+' with '<sp>=<sp>'.  You might want to tweak this a bit to avoid adding spaces at the ends of lines that end in '='.

Comment: `"You might want to tweak this a bit to avoid adding spaces at the ends of lines that end in '='"` - no such are present in Python code, as that would be a `SyntaxError`, and the code is running fine without errors.

Comment: Do you also want to fix operators with excessive spaces? `c    =       "c"` -> `c = "c"`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus theoretically yes, but such don't appear in the code I need to fix

Comment: True. I missed the mention of Python...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could capture for example an optional plus or minus followed by an equals sign in a group and match the surrounding whitespace chars.

In the replacement, use a backreference to what is captured and add a space on the left and on the right.

```php
\s*([*/+-]?=)\s*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h3TW6D/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/c5LT84)

For example (Thanks anubhava)

```
re.sub(r'\s*([*/+-]?=)\s*', r' \1 ', string)
```

Comment: I do not want the plus and minus to be optional - that would change `b+="b"` to `b = "b"`, whereas it should become `b += "b"`. I am going to do one replace run for each operator (`+`, `+=`, `-`, `-=`, etc.).

Comment: The one that does what I want is `\s*=\s*` to match equal signs - thank you ! You provided the clue with the optional whitespace (`\s*`) !

Comment: @Programmer The capture group matches an optional `+` `-` or `*` for example followed by `=`. That what is captured is used again in the replacement, this time with spaces on each side appended to get the right format.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. But - I'm not using `re.sub` for replacing, but rather Gedit's Search and replace dialog with the `Regular Expressions` box ticked.

Comment: @Programmer I think you can then still use the same pattern to search, and use the backreference in the replacement surrounded by spaces.

Comment: No, sadly Gedit's regex doesn't support backreference (`\1`) :(

Comment: @Programmer Did you try `$1` instead of `\1`?

Comment: No, it replaces with a plain `$1`

Comment: @Programmer I found this thread where they suggest a plugin https://askubuntu.com/questions/671745/gedit-search-and-replace-with-regular-expression. But you might also use Sublime for example, or Notepad++